# Explain "you can have functions that change other functions"

Tags: javascript, higher-order-functions

I was reading through [Eloquent JavaScript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html), when I came across this in chapter 5. :

> you can have functions that create new functions.
>
> ```
> function greaterThan(n) {
>   return function(m) { return m > n; };
> }
> var greaterThan10 = greaterThan(10);
> ```
>
> And you can have functions that change other functions.
>
> ```
> function noisy(f) {
>   return function(arg) {
>     console.log("calling with", arg);
>     var val = f(arg);
>     console.log("called with", arg, "- got", val);
>     return val;
>   };
> }
> noisy(Boolean)(0);
> //->calling with 0
> //->called with 0 - got false
> ```

My questions are:

- How are the above two examples different?
- How does *noisy* change *Boolean*?

Comment: I think that's just poorly worded. I think the point it's trying to make is that you can use callbacks by passing a function to another function. The "change" involved is really that it's consuming the result of the callback and modifying it.

Comment: "change other functions" appears misleading, even if it is trying to 'simply' the operation concept; the function is the same. It would be better expressed as "And you can have functions that *use* (by *wrapping*) other functions.."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that the argument to `noisy` is meant to be another function, rather than a "plain" value like a number.  So, yes, it creates a new anonymous function just like `greaterThan` does, but it's a wrapper around an existing function that modifies its behavior.

In this case, the wrapper just logs some messages before and after calling the original function `f`.  But you could do other things, like modifying its arguments or its return value.  For example, you can implement [partial function application](http://ejohn.org/blog/partial-functions-in-javascript/), which lets you provide *some* of the arguments for a function call at one point in the program, and "remember" those arguments in a new function that takes just the remaining arguments later.

Comment: It's hard consider this the correct answer until it makes clear that saying "changes the function" is somewhere between misleading and just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> How are the above two examples different?

`greaterThan` accepts a parameter, `n`, which is intended to be a number.

`noisy` accepts a parameter, `f`, which is intended to be a function that it can then call within it.

Where `greaterThan` only evaluates a number, `noisy` is much more flexible since it can accept any function and execute it.

> How does noisy change Boolean?

`noisy` returns an anonymous function that evaluates `Boolean` in the line that it stores its results in a variable called `val`.

Comment: So thus noisy does *not* change Boolean (or the function it originally referred to)..

Comment: Correct! It does not change it.

Comment: So then what is the quote *trying* to say?

Comment: `noisy(Boolean)(0)` executes `noisy`, with `Boolean` as the `f` parameter and `0` as the parameter passed in to `Boolean`. `0` always returns falsy. If this doesn't answer your question, I'm afraid you're not articulating it properly.